# Conditional rendering not working in react js with redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to create authentication system with MERN and redux tool kit, I am having problem with conditional rendering I have dashboard login and profile component now when I login current user is saved via persistor so I want to display profile component and when logout I want to show dashboard component but some how it is saving user but not working

Here is my login, dashboard and profile component

1 login

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Card, Button, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../../Redux/apiCalls";
import UpdateProfile from "../UpdateProfile/Updateprofile";

export default function Login() {
  const [username, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { isFetching, error } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      if(!currentUser){
        navigate('/')
      }else{
        login(dispatch, { username, password });
        navigate('/');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
    {!currentUser ? (<UpdateProfile/>):(
      <Card className="shadow-lg p-3 mb-2 bg-white rounded">
      <Card.Body>
        <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Log In</h2>
        {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group id="username">
            <Form.Label>UserName</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group id="password">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button
            disabled={isFetching}
            className="w-100 mt-4 mb-4"
            type="submit"
          >
            Log In
          </Button>
        </Form>
        <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
          <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot Password</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="w-100 text-center mt-3">
          Need an Account? <Link to="/signup">Sing Up</Link>
        </div>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    )}
      
    </>
  );
}
```

2 Dashboard

```js
import React from 'react'
import Profile from '../Profile/Profile';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Dashboard() {

  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  return (
    <>
    {!currentUser ? (<Profile/>):(
      <>
      <div>Dashboard</div>
      <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
      </>
    )}
    </>

  )
}
```

3 Profile

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Card, Button, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../../Redux/apiCalls";
import { reset } from "../../Redux/authRedux";

export default function Profile() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleLogout() {
    setError("");
    try {
      logout(dispatch);
      dispatch(reset());
      navigate("/login");
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to Log Out");
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card className="shadow-lg p-3 mb-2 bg-white rounded">
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Profile</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <strong>Email:</strong>
          <Link to="/update-profile" className="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">
            Update Profile
          </Link>
          <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
            <Button variant="link" onClick={handleLogout}>
              Log Out
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```

This are my all files related to redux

1 authSlice

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// Get currentUser from localstorage

const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",       // Global state
    initialState:{
        currentUser: currentUser ? currentUser : null,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false
    },
    reducers:{                    // All the reducer

        // Reset To initial state

        reset: (state)=>{
            state.currentUser = null
            state.isFetching = false
            state.error = false
        },

        // Login Reducers
        loginStart:(state)=>{
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        loginSuccess:(state,action)=>{
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFail:(state)=>{
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
        },

         // Register Reducers
         registerStart:(state)=>{
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        registerSuccess:(state,action)=>{
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        registerFail:(state)=>{
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
        },

        // Logout
        logoutSuccess:(state)=>{
            state.currentUser = null;
        }

    }
});

export const { 
    reset,
    loginStart,
    loginSuccess,
    loginFail,
    registerStart,
    registerSuccess,
    registerFail} = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

2 authService

```js
import { 
    reset,
    loginFail,
    loginStart,
    loginSuccess,
    registerFail,
    registerStart,
    registerSuccess } from './authRedux'
import {publicRequest} from '../requestMethods'

export const login = async (dispatch,user) =>{
    dispatch(loginStart());

    try {
        const response = await publicRequest.post('/auth/login', user)
        dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(loginFail())
    }
}

export const register = async (dispatch,user) =>{
    dispatch(registerStart())

    try {
        const response = await publicRequest.post('/auth/register',user)
        dispatch(registerSuccess(response.data));
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(registerFail())
    }
}

export const logout = (dispatch)=>{
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser')
    dispatch(reset());
}
```

3 Store

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from './authRedux'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { 
    persistReducer,
    persistStore,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    REGISTER,
    PURGE,
    PERSIST } from 'redux-persist';

const persistConfig={
    key:'root',
    version: 1,
    storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        auth: persistedReducer,
    },
    middleware:(getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck:{
            ignoreActions:[FLUSH,REGISTER,REHYDRATE,PERSIST,PURGE],
        },
    })
});

export let persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Everything else is working properly but not conditional rendering and I can't figure out why it is not working I am new to redux so if any one can help me.....

Answer (score 1):

You just mixed up your logic:

```js
    {!currentUser ? (<Profile/>):(
      <>
      <div>Dashboard</div>
      <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
      </>
    )}
```

means "if there is no current user, show the profile and if there is a current user show the Login".

Just remove the negation `!`:

```js
    {currentUser ? (<Profile/>):(
      <>
      <div>Dashboard</div>
      <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
      </>
    )}
```

Comment: I removed it now after I logout reset function fires and everything is back to initial state there is no current user in redux also but still at home page it renders profile component I don't have current user so it should render that div but it is not working